# nginx hot switch proxy_pass service

Tags: nginx

I have a Play Framework application that sits behind nginx server, configuration looking like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}
```

Obviously once in a while I need to restart my play service, but that takes time, so I need some kind of a hot switch mechanism, so that if I launch the app on port `9002` I could easily switch nginx to it. Is there any other way apart from editing the conf file of nginx and reloading/restarting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

Here is also a good [tutorial.](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/)